# How to delete recent repositories

Tags: github

I want to delete 2 repositories.
But I can't found way to delete

[image]

[image]

[image]

pic more

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete your repositories by following this

> Settings

> "Scroll Down" Danger Zone

> Click Delete this repository

> type{username}/{file} example - echo/data

> Click I understand the consequences, delete this repository

Comment: Thank you for reply.
Are you mean setting in Repo? I dont have setting you can see in pic 4.

Comment: The thing is if you cant access the setting it means you don't have the privilege to delete it. Are you the owner of the repo?

Comment: Well, sadly you cant delete it sorry.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite easy: Login -> Settings -> Scroll down: Danger Zone

Comment: Thank you for reply.
Are you mean setting in Repo? I dont have setting you can see in pic 4.

Answer (score 0):

- profile(position:right top) click >

[image: 1]

- Settings >
- Repositories >
- right display : "Leave" button click

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).