# Is there any way to edit GitHub Recent Repositories list (e.g. delete some items from it)?

Tags: github

It's quite annoying to see some unwanted items in the list `Recent Repositories`, which seems to be out of my control, every time I visit GitHub. For example, I want to remove the `wasm-bindgen` from [My Recent Repositories with some mosaic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgNd4.png) (I love this repo. It's just an exmaple :) )

I understand why the repos are here--because I have contributed or raised an issue to them. But sometimes I just don't want to see some of them here. I can archive my own repos, **but what can I do if the repo I want to get rid of is not my own repo?**

Thank you!

Related resources: 
[How to delete recent repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72509245/how-to-delete-recent-repositories)